# How to iterate through items in a class in jQuery

Tags: jquery, loops, toggle, iteration, show

I am looking to create a series of text boxes, one will appear after the other.  My set up is that I have all the boxes created (HTML) and hidden (jQuery).  I had it working for a predefined number of boxes (code for each was written using ids etc)  though I want to optimise it using a for loop.  This is what I have so far:

```
// Hide all (except first question) at the start
$(".Qs").hide();

// Now reveal next question on button click (button is in previous question)
$(".Qs").each(function(){
    $(".nextButton").click(function(){
        $(this).hide();
        $(".Qs").show();
    });
});
```

What it is doing is it showing all successive questions when I click the button of the first on.....I know it is doing this because of the line:
$(".Qs").show();

how can I get it to show only the next element in the Qs class?

Thank you very much!

Comment: Can you show your HTML?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try using the next() jquery method.

```js
// Hide all (except first question) at the start
$(".Qs").hide();

// Now reveal next question on button click (button is in previous question)
$(".nextButton").click(function(){
    $(this).hide();
    $(this).parent().next().show();
});
```

```html
<div><!-- Note first question doesn't have class -->
  Question 1
  <input type="button" class="nextButton" value="Next">
</div>
<div class="Qs">
  Question 2
  <input type="button" class="nextButton" value="Next">
</div>
<div class="Qs">
  Question 3
  <input type="button" class="nextButton" value="Next">
</div>
<div class="Qs">
  Question 4 (last)
</div>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Tested and it works as expected.

Answer (score 3):

If your goal is to show the first hidden question, change

```
$(".Qs").show();
```

to

```
$(".Qs:hidden:first").show();
```

Also, you don't want to hook up the `.nextButton` click handler inside an `each` on the questions; just once is sufficient. <s>Finally, your first code comment and the code after it didn't agree with each other; if you want to hide all but the first, you have to skip the first.</s> *(You've commented below that the first question doesn't have the `Qs` class, so...)*

So:

```
// Hide all (except first question) at the start
$(".Qs").hide();

// Now reveal next question on button click (button is in previous question)
$(".nextButton").click(function(){
  $(this).hide();
  $(".Qs:hidden:first").show();
});
```

Note that that uses jQuery enhancements to CSS selectors, and so can't be offloaded to the browser's built-in handling, but as this is a response to a button click by a user, the performance cost is imperceptible.

Note that this also doesn't care which `.nextButton` you click. To make it specific to a specific `.nextButton`, we'd need to see your HTML. That code would most likely use `closest` and `find`.

Live example:

```js
// Hide all (except first question) at the start
$(".Qs").hide();

// Now reveal next question on button click (button is in previous question)
$(".nextButton").click(function(){
  $(this).hide();
  $(".Qs:hidden:first").show();
});
```

```html
<div><!-- Note first question doesn't have class -->
  Question 1
  <input type="button" class="nextButton" value="Next">
</div>
<div class="Qs">
  Question 2
  <input type="button" class="nextButton" value="Next">
</div>
<div class="Qs">
  Question 3
  <input type="button" class="nextButton" value="Next">
</div>
<div class="Qs">
  Question 4 (last)
</div>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: this still shows all the hidden questions.....seems to do the same thing
ah see this is where my newness to jQuery is killing me! I'll look into "closest" and "find"

Comment: @Eoin: Not with the `:first` there it doesn't.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder also the click handler is not proper it is hiding the button... not the input

Comment: @T.J.Crowder it honestly is.....tried a refresh, tried restarting the browser....same thing :/

Comment: @Eoin: See the live example above.

Comment: @ArunPJohny: I think hiding the button is the goal (e.g., once it's been used to reveal the next question, it's served its purpose).